# Java (JDBC) : Alternatives for iteration of query results [ while(resultSet.next()) ]

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm searching for any alternative for this :

```
while(resultSet.next()){

}
```

---

- I am trying to avoid loop where they are not needed ;
- I am searching for the simpliest way to return one single result ;

---

Any brief annotation and answer is welcome.

Comment: For what? There is the bidirectional cursor, JPA entities, paging.

Comment: what do you want to do with the items of the result? Clarify your question what you want to achieve.

Comment: Briefly explain your functional module and its requirement i.e. where it is going to be used and for what it achieve then only best optimized solution can be suggested Since snippet you've written belongs to DS layer.

Comment: There are not well structured objectives for that. The context of using a alternative for that are just own methodologies and preferences. I had this question when trying to create a dynamic method to execute and return queries. And already edited the question with my main motivations.

Comment: `resultSet.next(); String result = resultSet.getString("columnName");` is about simplest you could go with a resultset API. However, I'd use Spring JDBC or similar.

Comment: Great , for some reason I was unable to use it like that last time I tried. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a `ResultSetIterator`:

```
class ResultSetIterator implements Iterator<ResultSet> {

    private final ResultSet r;
    private ResultSet next = null;

    public ResultSetIterator(ResultSet r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        if (next == null) {
            try {
                if (r.next()) {
                    next = r;
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                // NB: Log this error.
            }
        }
        return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public ResultSet next() {
        ResultSet n = next;
        next = null;
        return n;
    }

}
```

Then - with careful avoidance of repeating the iterator - perhaps using a `SingleUseIterable`:

```
/**
 * Makes sure the iterator is never used again - even though it is wrapped in an Iterable.
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
public static class SingleUseIterable<T> implements Iterable<T> {

    protected boolean used = false;
    protected final Iterator<T> it;

    public SingleUseIterable(Iterator<T> it) {
        this.it = it;
    }

    public SingleUseIterable(Iterable<T> it) {
        this(it.iterator());
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        if (used) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("SingleUseIterable already invoked");
        }
        used = true;
        // Only let them have it once.
        return it;
    }

}

/**
 * Adapts an {@link Iterator} to an {@link Iterable} for use in enhanced for loops.
 *
 * If {@link Iterable#iterator()} is invoked more than once, an {@link IllegalStateException} is thrown.
 *
 * @param <T>
 * @param i
 * @return
 */
public static <T> Iterable<T> in(final Iterator<T> i) {
    return new SingleUseIterable<>(i);
}
```

You can now do:

```
public void test() {
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    // ...
    try {
        for (ResultSet r : in(new ResultSetIterator(resultSet))) {
            // We're there.
        }

    } finally {
        if (resultSet != null) {
            resultSet.close();
        }

    }
}
```

Which is much more elegant. Remember to `close` your `ResultSet`.

Answer (score 1):

Read about ORM - Object/Relational Mapping:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping

I recommend Spring JPA or Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve a result without looping using the [**getString(int columnIndex)**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(int)) or **[getString(String columnLabel)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString(java.lang.String))** methods, for example:

```
resultSet.next();
String name = resultSet.getString("name");
```

Or with index:

```
 resultSet.next();
String name = resultSet.getString(1);
```